# How to find correct USB device configuration and interface for use in WebUSB?

Tags: javascript, usb, webapi, webusb

In WebUSB to connect to a device we must select a `configuration` and `interface`.
There's also the option to using an alternate interface.

How can I know which ones to use?
Do I need to know this beforehand or can I try to detect for each device?

```js
if (!device.configuration)    await device.selectConfiguration(0);

await device.claimInterface(device.configuration.interfaces[0].interfaceNumber)
```

Lets say I can have thermal printers and cameras for example, would I be able to detect for each one?

Also, how can I check if a device is already claimed? Do I have to check every interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I know which ones to use? Do I need to know this beforehand or
> can I try to detect for each device?

As [https://web.dev/devices-introduction/#:~:text=human-readable%20protocol.-,With,-WebUSB%2C%20without%20clear](https://web.dev/devices-introduction/#:%7E:text=human-readable%20protocol.-,With,-WebUSB%2C%20without%20clear) says, without clear documentation for this device and what USB commands this device supports, it's hard but still possible with lucky guessing.

Watch [Exploring WebUSB and its exciting potential](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpfZ8Nj3uiE) from Suz Hinton. You can also reverse-engineer this device by capturing raw USB traffic and inspecting [USB descriptors](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml) with external tools like Wireshark and built-in browser tools such as the internal page `about://usb-internals` in Chromium-based browsers.

> Lets say I can have thermal printers and cameras for example, would I
> be able to detect for each one?

Camera will likely be blocked. Inspecting your device in `about://usb-internals/` will tell you as you should see ["Blocked by WebUSB"](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2739609) when it's the case.

> Also, how can I check if a device is already claimed? Do I have to check every interface?

In general, I'd recommend https://web.dev/usb/ and https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml to start respectively with WebUSB and USB.

For your specific questions, `device.open()` and `device.claimInterface()` promises will fail if those actions can't be performed.